# I am using Http Form Adapter in Ping Federate. How to get user attributes from SAML Response?

Tags: saml-2.0, pingfederate

Http Form adapter serves as an authentication service in my application. I have not implemented any application on the Identity Provider to get user inputs.

Therefore, on successful authentication, SP verifies the user's signature and redirects to the application. At my target Resource, I receive an open token. Is it still possible to utilize the open Token Jar to read the user attributes from OTK?

**Note: ** In Service Provider, I use open token Adapter.

Also, please let me know if there is any other possible way of getting the user attributes other than using the open token adapter/http form adapter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous SP Adapters you can choose to use for your last mile integration with your application. The OpenToken Adapter is just one of them. If your application is in Java and you are using the SP OpenToken Adapter, then you would most likely use the Java OpenToken Agent implementation within your application to read the OTK ([documented in the Java Integration Kit](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/JIK252/Java+Integration+Kit)). If you look at the [Add Ons](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/products/downloads.html) list, there are actually 3 flavors of OTK Agents (.NET, Java and PHP from PingID. Ruby on Rails and Perl are available via respective Open Source repositories).

However, you are not limited to OpenToken Adapters. The Agentless Integration Kit is also very popular for SP/last-mile integration with PingFederate.

Unfortunately, the question is just too open ended for the Stackoverflow format. I would suggest talking to your Ping Identity Solution Architect who can help steer you in the right direction and ask the necessary follow-up questions on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If understand the question correctly, you desire attributes to be fulfilled that the web application can read and utilize.  This starts with the SP Connection configuration. I am going to assume you are using Active Directory and already configured that data source along with the Password Credential Validator (PCV) for the HTML Form IdP Adapter.  In the SP Connection you will need to extend the attribute contract to define the values to put into the SAML assertion and then use the Active Directory data source to fulfill the attributes. When the SAML assertion is received by the PingFederate SP role server, the SP Adapter maps the attribute values from the SAML assertion into the OpenToken.  When your application receives the OpenToken, it can read the values.